# How to get template variable from within a custom template tag

Tags: python, django, templates

In Django, is there a way for a custom template tag to have access to the current template's variables passed on by the view?

My first thought is to make a parameter where the user can place the template variable manually but if my custom template tag can access the variable itself then it would be much better!

To illustrate, I want to get rid of the parameter `templatevar`

```
@register.simple_tag
def sampletag(templatevar):
    return templatevar
```

Comment: From a testability / maintainability / robustness POV explicitely passing variables is better than relying on what might or not be set in the context. This is of course no hard&fast rule - sometimes having your templatetag taking the whole context (cf Daniel Roseman's answer) is the best solution, but you can definitly not rely on the the variable being set in the context nor - if it is - being what you expect, so you'll have to code around to gracefully handle those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `takes_context` parameter to the decorator.

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def sampletag(context):
    return context['templatevar']
```

See the [template tags documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags).